# How to add value of y-axis under the x-axis labels in highchart with given dataset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to attach my yaxis values under the xaxis labels. I've prepare a picture to illustrate what I'm trying to accomplish below.

[image]

Basically I want to grab the first value of the corresponding year and set it as a label under the x-axis labels.

Here is my fiddle with the data set attached. http://jsfiddle.net/5df2mjmm/

Currently here is how I am setting the year only for the x-axis

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%d %b %Y' //ex- 01 Jan 2016
    }
  }
```

I'm also trying to figure out how to make every year show on the x-axis and not just 2008,2010,2012,2014,2016.

I've been at this for hours with no luck..I would very much appreciate if any highchart gurus can help me out with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highcharts will not render all years when there isn't enough space for labels. You can force Highcharts to render those labels by setting `xAxis.tickInterval: 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000`.

Regarding the issue with labels, you need to use `xAxis.labels.formatter`, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5df2mjmm/9/

And demo with `tickInterval` set: http://jsfiddle.net/5df2mjmm/4/

Snippet:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  tickInterval: 265 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {

      var currentX = new Date(this.value),
        xIndex;

      // Because labels in Highcharts are rendered at 1st of Month,
      // But data is last day of the month, we need to jump to the last day of the January:
      currentX.setUTCDate(31);

      // xData stores base x-values for series, get current date index:
      xIndex = this.axis.series[0].xData.indexOf(+currentX);

      return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d %b %Y', this.value) + '<br>' + this.axis.series[0].yData[xIndex]; // the same as with xData, we can use yData
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Hey Pawel I appreciate your help very much. Just a quick question around the numbers below the years. They are all appearing undefined. Any ideas? Thanks again!!

Comment: Which timezone you are? Both demos above work for me. Could you check `xIndex`? If it's not -1? Try also setting `currentX.setHours(hoursOffset)`.

Comment: Hi Pavel looking more in to your example i found that the data set is showing 2007 and not 2008. Take a look at the console.log http://jsfiddle.net/5df2mjmm/7/ here is the first timestamp Mon Dec 31 2007 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST) there is no 2007 in record? it's still showing undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: one last update. When I switch to currentX.setDate(30); first year always undefined and for next year it shows last years dec 31 number in next years label..thank you again for your help

Comment: My mistake, there should be `setUTCDate(31)`, not `setDate(31)`. Additionally, don't remove `+` from the `indexOf()`, otherwise it won't fine corresponding values.. Updated answer.